# Impossible to compare String

Tags: java

Why "==" or equals method doesn't work ?

```
        String levelSetting = ManageLogFile.getLevel(); 
        if (levelSetting != Log.Level.DEBUG.toString()) {
            System.out.println(Log.Level.DEBUG.toString());
            System.out.println(levelSetting);
            log.setData(null);
            }
```

With Result displayed :

```
DEBUG
DEBUG
```

It's the same String... But != doesn't work...
I have also tried with equals method.. and same problem
I have compare lenght and it's 5 for both.

Comment: The reason that `==` and `!=` don't work most of the time is explained in the dup.  If `String.equals(Object)` really doesn't work, then the two strings are NOT equal.  (Hint: use a debugger and examine the strings character by character ...)

Comment: Hint: whitespaces are the same color as their background.